# Is there an alternative in Pandas for the R combination lapply(split(df, df$group), fun)?

Tags: python, r, pandas, subset, lapply

I want to run

`regr = ElasticNetCV(l1_ratio=l1_ratios, alphas=alphas_list).fit(x_train, y_train)  pd.DataFrame(regr.predict(x_test),columns=['y_pred'])`

for a pandas dataframe for different subsets according to a group value. I want to avoid the following:

```
for groupid in df['group'].unique():
  code
  pd.concat(...., axis=1)
```

A simple apply() would run the function for each observation, which is inefficient. R allows to use lapply() by splitting the dataframe in different subsets. Is there an alternative in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each of `x_train`, `y_train` and `x_test` is a dataframe with a column `group` and `l1_ratios` and `alphas_list` are global, you could e.g. do something like this, which stores the predictions for each group in a dictionary with the group id's as keys. I doubt that the grouping i.e. looping part of the code will be crucial w.r.t. runtime.

```
def fun(x_tr, y_tr, x_te):
    regr = ElasticNetCV(l1_ratio=l1_ratios, alphas=alphas_list).fit(x_tr, y_tr)
    pd.DataFrame(regr.predict(x_te), columns=['y_pred'])

res = {}
for groupid in df.groupby['group'].unique():
    res[groupid] = fun(
        x_train[x_train.group == groupid],
        y_train[y_train.group == groupid],
        x_test[x_test.group == groupid]
    )
```